# Java: Best way to parallely read from a list and then put in a ConcurrentHashMap and parallely read from the same Map

Tags: java, loops, collections

I am getting a list of object from a query.
I want to iterate through this list and pass the values as parameters to another query.The result of the second query needs to be put in a Map.

How can i iterate through the list parallely and write in the map simultaneously.

i should be able to put multiple values in the map at the same time and also read from the map at the same time.
Pseudo code to explain:

```
List<Student> student= select rollNo,name,class from Student;
    student.forEach(rollNbr -> 
List<StudentMetaData> studentMetaData = select rollNo,address,phoneNbr from StudentMetaData where rollno = rollNbr);

ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>();

map.put(studentMetaData.getRollNbr,studentMetaData.getAddress);
```

I want the best solution to do this.

Comment: Use a parallel stream.

Comment: What's your question or problem? How to access the map or how to write parallel/multi-threaded code?

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for the solution ..
But Parallel streams use a thread pool to launch multiple threads that do parts of work, and all of this adds a lot of overhead to what otherwise would be a simple processing task. You will only start seeing gains if the amount of processing required is large enough where doing it in parallel offsets the setup time.

Comment: @Thomas how to write parallel/multi-threaded code..to read from a list and simultaneously write to a map..Looking for the best solution which doesn't impact the performance

Comment: You want parallel iteration that doesn't use multiple threads? Your requirements are unclear to say the least.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are after. Assuming you didn't just copy the text of your comment to shmosel this would imply you already have some knowledge on writing multi-threaded code and the tradeoffs that are involved. So what exactly are you asking about? How to add elements to the map in the `forEach(...)` performend on `student`?

Comment: @Thomas Looks like it's copied from [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-disadvantage-of-always-using-parallel-stream-instead-of-stream-while-performing-operations-on-collections-in-Java#:~:text=Parallel%20streams%20use,the%20setup%20time.). But to the extent that it's applicable here, it's a critique of the requirement, not my solution.

Comment: @Thomas i have some knowledge of stream APIs of Java 8.But i dont prefer it because of its impact on heap and CPU usage..I m looking for something better than this.Is it a good idea to create a threadpool and use TaskExecutor for this?Or do u have a better solution..

Comment: @shmosel yes, that's true. That's why I was confused about the "iterate in parallel" and "thread pools are costly" statements which seem to conflict unless there's some catch the OP didn't tell us, like "optimize iteration so that parallelism is used if there are gains to be expected". However, I probably interpeted too much into this. - Btw, good catch on the Quora quote :)

Comment: "i dont prefer it because of its impact on heap and CPU usage" - do you realize that parallel streams will use task executors as well, especially a shared thread pool if you don't specify anything else? Sure, you could do it yourself but would it _really_ be worth the effort? If this is for training then go ahead, if this is because you're worried about performance - do some profiling to check if using parallel streams is an issue at all. If you face performance issues that is, if you don't face any, just don't bother - don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @shmosel.. I have read this at lot of places that stream APIs are not always the best solution.So was looking for something better than that.

Comment: @Thomas I was just worried about the performance..But you are write i will do some profiling and check if it really impacts.

Comment: They're not always the best solution because the benefits of parallelization don't always offset the costs of multithreading. Using your own thread pool is not likely to change that. FWIW, I think multithreading is probably worthwhile here, assuming the secondary query is at all resource-intensive.

Comment: Btw, it might be worthwhile to investigate a reactive approach which would let process query results as they come in instead of waiting for all of them to be transferred. Of course this only works if the database driver supports this so have a look at this: https://r2dbc.io/ (I didn't use it myself yet but it looks promising).

Comment: @Thomas will check this.Thanks